# How to move data from server redis to server redis other by code or by GUI redis?

Tags: c#, .net, redis

Recently, I have a issue can't move data include: key and value from this server redis to server redis other. How way do it?
Please help me. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the Redis servers you can use a combination of the commands available here: -

https://redis.io/commands/keys

https://redis.io/commands/dump

https://redis.io/commands/restore

https://redis.io/commands/migrate

I tend to keep track of the keys I have set so I can flush REDIS if I need to.

Someone else with a deeper knowledge may have a better way, but I would either: -

1. List the keys you need to migrate
2. Dump them all
3. Move over the dumped data
4. Restore them all on the new server

OR

Use the MIGRATE command like this (quoted from the REDIS.IO site)

> Migrating multiple keys with a single command call Starting with Redis
> 3.0.6 MIGRATE supports a new bulk-migration mode that uses pipelining in order to migrate multiple keys between instances without incurring
> in the round trip time latency and other overheads that there are when
> moving each key with a single MIGRATE call.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the server and want to do a live migration you can use [RIOT](https://github.com/redis-developer/riot).  There is more information in the Redis->Redis Cookbook and documentation